# Finding the minimum from a sorted rotated array with duplicates

Tags: javascript, sorting, binary-search

Is this an efficient way of finding the minimum using binary search?

```
//Find the minimum in a sorted rotated list of numbers
function findmin(arr, low, high){
  if(low==high)
    return arr[low];

  if(arr[low]<arr[high])
    return arr[low];

  if((high-low) == 1)
    return Math.min(arr[high], arr[low]);
  var mid = Math.floor((low+high)/2);

  //search right side
  if(arr[mid] >= arr[low]){
    return findmin(arr, mid+1, high);
  }
  else{
    return findmin(arr, low, mid);
  }    
}
var arr = [8,8,8,8,8,1];
console.log(findmin(arr, 0, arr.length-1));
```

Comment: What is "the minimum"? The smallest value?

Comment: You might want to put "binary search" on the title before people suggest running the array through `Math.min`.

Comment: There are several points I don't understand. 1) You talk about a _rotated_  array: what does it mean? 2) You talk about a _sorted_ array and you write `if(arr[low]<arr[high])`, which shouldn't happen when sorted _desc_ like in your example. 3) Using other values in `arr` gives weird results, such as `[9,8,8,8,8,1]` giving `8`, `[8,8,8,8,6,1]` giving 6, or `[8,8,8,8,1,0]` giving `1`.

Comment: `if(arr[low]<arr[high])
    return [whatever]` looks _wrong - please_ elaborate on _sorted rotated array_. Is there a javascript convention whether `high` is inclusive or exclusive? I'd test for "2 elements, at most" first.

Comment: A sorted array ex:1 2 3 4 5, becomes a rotated array after we move n elements from the front to the end. So 3 4 5 1 2 is a rotated version of the input (rotated 2 times).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *array* arr *with values that are ascending, after rotation if necessary*.
For any range of indexes of length n there can be at most one 0≤i<n with `arr[low+i]>arr[low+((i+1)%n)]`: *the drop*. If arr[low]<arr[high], that i is n-1, and arr[low] is indeed the minimum.
With mid = Math.floor((low+high)/2), if `arr[low]<arr[mid]`, there is a drop from mid to high; if `arr[low]>arr[mid]`, the drop is in this range.
With duplicates allowed, I don't see how to exclude any range when `arr[low]≡arr[mid]≡arr[high]`: all values could be equal, or one could be smaller, and there is no way to tell without looking at each and every one: bisecting does not help efficiency in this case, and not visiting both halves is wrong. (No adverbial use of naïve in English?)
(Revisiting [how to answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), I notice the question is on the very edge of *on topic* or not, not dispersing suspicions about answers like this one.)